# accessing Json key-value pair for angularjs controller using services

Tags: angularjs, http, dependency-injection, get

I have been trying to use data from my service for a chart in my angularjs controller.I have made a service in service.js which i am using in my controller.All i get is the Object array,but when i try to access values inside the Object array ,it throws errors for each approach i use .Following is what i am doing

```
 My Service 

  var demoService= angular.module('demoService',[])
 .service('myService',function($http,$q){
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('http://enlytica.com/RSLivee/rest/census').then(function(data)
        {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        });
this.getPlayers=function()
{
    return deferred.promise;
}
})
```

My Controller

```
 angular.module("app.controllers", [])
.controller("gaugeCtrl", ["$scope","config","myService",
function ($scope,config,myService) {
var promise=myService.getPlayers();
promise.then(function(data)
        {
    $scope.players=data.data;
    //console.log($scope.players.Tweets);
     ($scope.players.Tweets).each(function(index, element) {
        console.log(element.FAVOURITE_COUNT); 
     });
    });
    return $scope.gaugeHome = {
      gaugeData: {
        maxValue: 9000,
        animationSpeed: 100,
        val: 1000


      },
      gaugeOptions: {
        lines: 12,
        angle: 0,
        lineWidth: 0.47,
        pointer: {
          length: 0.6,
          strokeWidth: 0.03,
          color: "#555555"
        },
        limitMax: "false",
        colorStart: config.secondary_color,
        colorStop: config.secondary_color,
        strokeColor: "#F5F5F5",
        generateGradient: !0,
        percentColors: [
          [0, config.secondary_color],
          [1, config.secondary_color]
        ]
      }
    }
```

I have also included the service Module in my app.js :

```
   var app = angular.module("app",["demoService"])
```

How can i access a particular value for my gaugectrl properly .Is following a wrong way to access it ?

```
 ($scope.players.Tweets).each(function(index, element) {
        console.log(element.FAVOURITE_COUNT);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you add the errors you're facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everything is working. It seems like you are trying to access the objects in the array incorrectly.

I think you want to use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
someArray.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
   // Do stuff here.
});
```

I made a simplified version of your code:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope, $q, $http) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('http://enlytica.com/RSLivee/rest/census').then(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });
  var promise = deferred.promise;

  promise.then(function(data) {    
    var tweets = [];
    var total = 0;
    $scope.players = data.data;
    ($scope.players.Tweets).forEach(function(element) {
      console.log(element);
      tweets.push({FAVOURITE_COUNT: element. FAVOURITE_COUNT, TWEET_ID: element.TWEET_ID});
      total += element.FAVOURITE_COUNT;
    });
    $scope.something.tweets = JSON.stringify(tweets, null, 2);
    $scope.something.favoriteTotal = total;
  });
  $scope.something = {};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>
  {{ something.favoriteTotal }}
  <pre>{{ something.tweets }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi DTing , could you tell me how can i push one of the  one Values from JSON (Lets say total of FAVOURITE_COUNT ) to the Gauge chart.

Comment: I'm not seeing in your code how you are getting data to your gauge chart. Can make a fiddle? I'm guessing you just get a total in your promise.then callback and set some value on your controller.

Comment: i dont have a problem in fetching the data but when i try to insert the data to the gauge it doesnt accept it 

             ** ' gaugeData:  {
              maxValue: 3e3,
              animationSpeed: 100,
              val:parseInt(myService.getdata())}' **  

but it does accept a numeric value if returned from the service